# Headset works on music but not on call

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, audio, samsung-galaxy-ace, headphones

I have a weird problem. My headset works with music, but not with calls. The headset icon shows, but the sound still comes from the phone (instead of the headset) when I make a call. Music works fine with the headset.

This is what I'm using:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by headset? Earphones?

Comment: @LiamW edited my question with a picture of what I'm using

Comment: The built in earphones, I see. This is strange, and I'm not sure on the answer so will post as comment first: Have you checked the dialer settings? Open the dialer, then press Menu->Settings.

Comment: @LiamW There's not much setting about it there. I am using Cynogendmod 7.2 on Galaxy Ace BTW.

Comment: Weird problem of the month! :) Suggestion: did you try using another set of headsets?

Comment: Could be audio-routing bug when plugged into headset when in-call?

Comment: Somebody reported [this](https://code.google.com/p/cyanogenmod/issues/detail?id=4257), [here](https://code.google.com/p/cyanogenmod/issues/detail?id=2950) might be best to star the issue... **be aware, that even though the issues show different models, the code remains the same across devices**

Comment: This seems to be common and samsung admits it. Many headphone microphones don't work with the S3.